# Disable Media uploader to users

Tags: posts, uploads, media

Is it possible to disable the Media uploader to anyone lower than an admin, but have the select file(s) window show?

Comment: So you want to disable the uploader, but show the uploader? Or do you actually want to disable the selection of existing images?

Comment: Im using ACF and the uploader field uses the Media uploader, Can you make it so instead of the Media/library window showing, it goes directly to the Select file window?

Comment: Ooh, have you asked ACF support? 3rd party plugins are off topic here, someone could answer in the generic sense? But not in the ACF context

Comment: But it uses the Media Library, surely there is a way to disable them from viewing it but still allow them to attach a file/upload a file to the post?